# Semantic UI and the grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, semantic-ui, grid-system

I´m a Bootstrap guy, and find Semantic UI, i think it´s awesome. So i´m in the basic learning process, and most of all the GRID SYSTEM.

I read and experiment my own excercise with the grid, and find that works with 16 columns grid, columns size can be definied in the row:

```
<div class="ui grid">
 <div class="five column row">
   <div class="column">1</div>
   ...
 </div>
```

... and in the column itself:

```
<div class="eight wide column"></div>
```

And learn about stackable and doubling columns, and learn that you can specify colums sizes for each three devices ( mobile, tablet, computer ).

```
<div class="six wide tablet eight wide computer column"></div>
```

**My question is, since it´s a 16 columns based grid, it´s not divisible in 3 with equal values how do i get 3 columns in a specific device?** Maybe this can be done with doubling but i need a solid solution, i mean, don´t depend in the other devices sizes.

In Bootstrap it would be as simple as ( example of small screen, 12 columns grid ):

```
<div class="col-sm-4">Content here</div>
```

Thanks!

Sebastián.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="ui equal width three column grid">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
</div>
```

If I understand your question right this should work for you.

[Grid Example - Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/examples/grid.html)